# source code of a website that is blocked access to right click and Source code

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser

I wanna see the source code of this website but I can't right click or anything! can someone help me with it?

website link: https://vcard2.themefix.ir/full-rtl/about.html

Comment: google search : open dev tools keyboard shortcut,for example in mac is : option/command/i

Comment: depending on your browser open devtools from the browser menu instead of using rightclick/ keyboard shortcut

Comment: @Vaggelis dude, did you even try to open the website or just comment and go? I am a developer, I know these things! this site blocked control + and right click, even if you try to use tools to show source code, it writes in source code that it is blocked!

Comment: @s.Bergmann thanks for your answer but I know F12 shortcut and ..., but it won't work on this specific website

Comment: @Vaggelis ok I'll check again on your google search

Comment: well go on the browser settings, additional tools, dev tools. site blocked your keyboard and right click, but not your dev tools as a whole.

Comment: just go to `view-source:https://vcard2.themefix.ir/full-rtl/about.html`. The source code itself is quite sneaky but it still exists, scroll down to line 21152.

Comment: @AliJebali https://freeimage.host/i/screenshot-2022-09-18-002027.iRdWV1

Comment: This is still just "open dev tools" and/or "view page source". If the page is hijacking all key and mouse events, then don't use those: you don't need them to open dev tools or view page source. Just click your browser's settings/options icon, and then open dev tools/page source through the browser's own menu system.

Comment: For Firefox you can also just open the dev tools by pressing F12. Then open the website while keeping the dev tools open.

Comment: @Vaggelis OMG, NICE, I'll try all your answer right now

Comment: the answer of @tacoshy Helped and I accessed throw it. thank you all for your fast answers

Comment: But - oh no! - `<!DOCTYPE html><!-- Source code not available ... -->` whatever can we do?! I truly despise the things some of us (are made to) do :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While a page can intercept and block clicks and keystrokes *on the page itself*, it can't do the same for actions outside the page. Focus on something outside the page (such as the address bar) and use a keyboard shortcut that opens the source - Control-U, in many browsers.

But the source text of that site is also hard to get to, because there are many empty lines. Use a text processor or some other tool to replace multiple occurrences of `\r\n` with a single `\r\n`, and you'll be left with the readable source code in front of you.

[image]

Comment: I have tried this, but it doesn't helped me, or maybe I'm doing something wrong. I copied all text in that page and go to notepad++ and do what you told. nothing special happened

Comment: Check "Regular expression" and type in `(\r\n)+` in the "Find what" tab, and then press "Replace all". Depending on settings you might have only newlines and not linefeeds, in which case search for `\n+` instead